# How can i separate this div overlap

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to build a web form and the divs keep overlapping.
I am confused as to why.
I have separated all into separate divs and I'm trying to have them stack one after the other.
How can I get all the divs to be in separate rows such that it doesnt overlap.

This is the component.html file:

```
<div>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        
        <div class="centerNavBar">
            <a mat-button href="fa-dashboard">Back</a>
            &nbsp;
            <span class="headSpacer">Damage Assessment Tool</span>        
            &nbsp;
            <a mat-button href="">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>

<div>
    <mat-sidenav-container class="MainContainter">
        <!--SideNav-->
        <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
            <div>
                <a mat-button href="">Message Board</a>
            </div>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content class="MainContent">
            <mat-card>
                <mat-card-header class="sect">Create report:</mat-card-header>
                <br><br>
                <mat-card-content>
                    <!--Div for form-->
                    <div> 
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <input
                                #MOCDateInput
                                matInput type= "Date"
                                required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                            <br>
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Comment</mat-label>
                            <input  
                                #DescriptionInput
                                placeholder="--"
                                matInput type= "string"
                                required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <br>
                        <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-label>Facility In Question</mat-label>
                        <input  
                                #MOCFacilityInput  
                                placeholder="--"
                                matInput type= "string"
                                required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="MOCMap">
                        <!--Div for Map-->
                        <div class="map-container">
                            <div class="map-frame">
                                <div id="map"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Div for buttons-->
                    <div>   
                        <input  
                            style="display: none;"
                            #ImageInput
                            type= "file"
                            (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="ImageInput.click()">Upload An Image</button>
                        &nbsp;
                        <button mat-raised-button 
                        type="submit" 
                        (click)="createMOCForm(MOCFacilityInput.value, DescriptionInput.value, MOCDateInput.value)" color="primary">Submit Report</button> 
                    </div>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

The image shows the overlap
[image]

This is the global css file:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";


html, body {height: 100%}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Roboto;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
}

.sect{
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 850px;
    background-color: white;
}


.centerNavBar {
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding: auto;
}


.headSpacer{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

/*map*/
.map-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 50px;
}

.map-frame {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Any help would be appreciate, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want it to be laid out as

- Form
- Map
- Buttons

Correct? It seems that only the map is a problem. Try removing the `position: absolute` and associated styles, your `.map-container` should look like this:

```
.map-container {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

---

Setting `position:absolute` is causing the map to appear in the middle of the page, and disregard any layout. `position:absolute` puts the map some place relative to the nearest parent element with `postition` set to something.